# Google Adsense Auto Ads not showing on my blog

Tags: google-adsense

I have a blog that google already approved to for its adsense account. I have successfully implemented it on my wordpress blog but unfortunately i can't see any ads on my blog.

I even don't know how much days it will take to showing ads on my blog. 2 days already passed. I need help to setup it correctly if i did any mistake or guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Try to turn off ad-block. It can by one option.

Comment: @PetrPrůcha i don't have any ad-blocker on my browser

Comment: Try asking AdSense support specialists, https://www.google.com/adsense/start/get-started/contact-sales/ if your blog have 300k page-views per month.

Answer (score 1):

For AdSense to show ads on your site, you need to check the following things -

1. Your AdSense account needs to be activated and not a Hosted Account (you can verify this by click on your Account name at the top right and seeing the status, if it is a Hosted Account, it will display in a red font). A Hosted Account cannot show ads on non-Google site, it can still be used to show ads on blogger.com or on a youtube channel
2. On your site's root, check for a file ads.txt, if it is there, then please check which AdSense account is mentioned in that file
3. Whether your script is properly put on all the pages

If all these three points are addressed, then you would start seeing ads pretty soon.